# Remove div which has no content or only has white space using regex

Tags: javascript, regex

My HTML contains `divs` some of it dont have any content and some contains only white space. I want to remove those `divs` with regular expression.

I written code but it seems not right. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uy252zmt/1/)

```
var patt= new RegExp("<div></div>");
document.querySelector('.wrapper').innerHTML.replace(patt,'')
```

Comment: [*Do not do this*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454). <:o

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. String.replace() does not change the original string.
2. You should use the "g" flag to remove all empty divs and not only the first occurrence.

```js
var patt = new RegExp("<div>\\s*</div>", "g");
var wrapperDiv = document.querySelector('.wrapper');
wrapperDiv.innerHTML = wrapperDiv.innerHTML.replace(patt, '')
```

Answer (score 3):

Use dom manipulation instead of regex to modify html content

```js
var els = document.querySelectorAll('.wrapper div'),
  el;
for (var i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
  el = els[i];
  if ((el.textContent || el.innerText).trim() == '') {
    el.parentNode.removeChild(el)
  }
}
```

```css
div:not(.wrapper) {
  background-color: #ff0000;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 5px
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div>text</div>
  <div></div>
  <div>text</div>
  <div>text</div>
  <div><span></span>
  </div>
  <div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Arun your code looks good but I want to get this done by using regex

Comment: @amit—you can't reliably parse HTML with a regular expression because HTML is not a regular language.

Comment: ok understood but without using HTML tag how to get this done

Answer (score 0):

Add `\\s*`, inbetween those tags.. `\\s*` matches zero or more white-spaces(vertical aswell as horizontal white-space).

```
var patt= new RegExp("<div>\\s*</div>", "g");
```

```js
var s = '<div class="wrapper">\n    <div>text</div>\n    <div></div>\n    <div>text</div>\n    <div>text</div>\n    <div></div>\n</div>'
alert(s.replace(/<div>\s*<\/div>/g, ''))
```

or

```js
var s = '<div class="wrapper">\n    <div>text</div>\n    <div></div>\n    <div>text</div>\n    <div>text</div>\n    <div></div>\n</div>'
alert(s.replace(/\s*<div>\s*<\/div>/g, ''))
```

Comment: Will this detect newlines in the content?

Comment: @AvinashRaj: I tried your code but it is not working. http://jsfiddle.net/uy252zmt/2/